# 2D Discrete Fourier Transform and Inverse DFT in matlab

Tags: matlab, dft

I am currently implementing 2D DFT and IDFT for images in matlab without using built-in library. I successfully output a spectrum image after DFT but I fail to get back the original image after IDFT.
Here's my code for DFT

```
input = im2double(img_input);
[M, N] = size(input);
Wm = zeros(M, M);
Wn = zeros(N, N);

for x = 1:M-1
    for y = 1:N-1
        input(x, y) = input(x, y) * (-1)^(x + y);
    end
end

for u = 0:M-1
    for x = 0:M-1
        Wm(u+1, x+1) = exp(-li * pi * 2 * u * x/ M);
    end    
end

for v = 0:N-1
    for y = 0:N-1
        Wn(v+1, y+1) = exp(-li * pi * 2 * v * y / N);
    end    
end
F = Wm * input * Wn / 200;
output = im2uint8(log(1 + abs(F)));
```

IDFT:

```
[M, N] = size(input);
Wm = zeros(M, M);
Wn = zeros(N, N);

for x = 0:M-1
    for u = 0:M-1
        Wm(x+1, u+1) = exp(2 * pi * 1i * u * x/ M);
    end    
end

for y = 0:N-1
    for v = 0:N-1
        Wn(y+1, v+1) = exp(2 * pi * 1i * v * y / N);
    end
end

f = Wm * input * Wn;

for x = 1:M-1
    for y = 1:N-1
        f(x, y) = f(x, y) * (-1)^(x + y);
    end
end

output = im2uint8(abs(f));
```

I multiply the input by (-1)^(x+y) in order to shift the coordinate origin. I have no idea why I can't get back the original image after performing IDFT on the DFTed image.

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lmq4D.png)

[Image after DFT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WemWl.png)

[Image after IDFT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvx1O.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine. To get `output` of the second function to be identical to `img_input` of the first function, I had to make the following changes:

1st function:

```
F = Wm * input * Wn;                % Don't divide by 200 here.
output = im2uint8(log(1 + abs(F))); % Skip this line altogether
```

2nd function: Make sure `F` from the first function is used as `input` here.

```
f = Wm * input * Wn / N / M;        % Divide by N*M, proper normalization
```

Note that the normalization is usually put into the IDFT, but you can also put it into the DFT if you prefer. The normalization by 200 is not correct though.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Now I changed my code of DFT to not divide by 200 and output im2uint8(abs(F)). Then, I changed the code of IDFT as what you suggested as well and output im2uint8(abs(f)) again. However, my output of IDFT is all black this time. I still couldn't get my original image.

Comment: I think I have figured it out. Thanks a lot for the advice.

Comment: @Nighost: yeah, if you throw away all phase information and round away so much relevant data, you won’t be able to reconstruct your original image. `log` and `abs` are for display only, always keep the full, floating-point complex data from your DFT to compute the inverse.